# Migrate calculations from VBA to SQL?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures, database-performance

I manage an application built on Access with some VBA code that takes its data from:

- Inputs by the user through Access forms
- Tables in Sybase (that are linked through Access)
- Local tables in Access

The application is used to make some financial calculations. Our calculations need a lot of conditions and are mostly some complex calculations (fractions, multiplications...)

My question is : **is VBA faster than Sybase to do the calculations ?** 
(Please notice than when we do our calculations it takes our 3 kinds of data sources)

I was thinking about migrate all of the calculations to Sybase as some stored procedures and call it from the VBA code with parameters, and wait from an output from Sybase.

PS: another reason why I am asking that is because we consider as a long term project to migrate our Access application to a thin client(prob web-based), and if all the calculations are already on the server/database side it could maybe be easier? What do you think?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, I would pass the form based variables (user entry) as parameters into a stored procedure, then fetch the other variables as needed from tables within the SP. This avoids sending too much data to the client as the form is opening. This abstracts the logic from VBA code (or any specific front-end language), making it easier to eventually move to a thin layer. You can also recompile independent stored procedures as needed, instead of deploying another instance of your code (much harder usually).

If there are a lot of parameters coming from the form or local tables, consider passing them in as a structured data type within Sybase. The procedure cache within Sybase is extremely powerful and after initial compilation as fast as any other procedural language.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion Daniel.
By any chance have you got any documentation on structured data type of Sybase ? (I have never heard of that). Sybase is not that used and there is not a lot of doc referring to it...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the calculations.  Sybase will be better at doing calculations that involve grouping data, but complex calculations like fractions, etc... would be faster to do in code.  Also it's just better practice to separate out business logic from data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Our calculations needs a lot of conditions and are mostly some complex calculations (fractions, multiplications...).

Comment: I would keep your data in your database, and do the calculations in your application.  Using a compiled language like C# would be faster but VBA should do the trick, and you will then always have clean data.